# Formatting the contents of pandas column. Removing trailing text and digits

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I've used BeautifulSoup and pandas to create a csv with columns that contain error codes and corresponding error messages.

Before formatting, the columns look something like this

```
-132456ErrorMessage
-3254Some other Error 
-45466You've now used 3 different examples. 2 more to go. 
-10240 This time there was a space.    
-1232113That was a long number.
```

I've successfully isolated the text of the codes like this:

```
dfDSError['text']  = dfDSError['text'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('-0123456789'))
```

This returns just what I want.

But I've been struggling to come up with a solution for the codes.

I tried this:

```
dfDSError['codes'] = dfDSError['codes'].replace(regex=True,to_replace= r'\D',value=r'')
```

But that will append numbers from the error message to the end of the code number. So for the third example above instead of 45466 I would get 4546632.  Also I would like to keep the leading minus sign.

I thought maybe that I could somehow combine rstrip() with a regex to find where there was a nondigit or a space next to a space and remove everything else, but I've been unsuccessful.

```
for_removal = re.compile(r'\d\D*')
dfDSError['codes']  = dfDSError['codes'].map(lambda x: x.rstrip(re.findall(for_removal,x)))                         
TypeError: rstrip arg must be None, unicode or str
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
dfDSError[['code','text']] = dfDSError.text.str.extract('([-0-9]+)(.*)', expand=True)
print (dfDSError)
                                                text      code
0                                       ErrorMessage   -132456
1                                  Some other Error      -3254
2  You've now used 3 different examples. 2 more t...    -45466
3                   This time there was a space.        -10240
4                            That was a long number.  -1232113
```